# Fetching a list with Lagom framework

Tags: java, microservices, lagom

I'm VERY new to Lagom framework and I have absolutely no idea what I'm doing. I have a simple CRUD lagom application that does work, but I can't figure out how to retrieve a list.

So this is what I have for now, but I'm getting

```
@Override
    public ServiceCall<NotUsed, Source<Movie, ?>> getMovies() {
        return request -> {
            CompletionStage<Source<Movie, ?>> movieFuture = session.selectAll("SELECT * FROM movies")
                    .thenApply(rows -> rows.stream()
                    .map(row -> Movie.builder()
                        .id(row.getString("id"))
                        .name(row.getString("name"))
                        .genre(row.getString("genre"))
                        .build()));
                    //.thenApply(TreePVector::from));
                    //.thenApply(is -> is.collect(Collectors.toList()))

            return movieFuture;
        };
    }
```

but I'm getting a `[Java] Type mismatch: cannot convert from Stream<Object> to Source<Movie,?>` error on the `rows.stream()` line.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the return type should be a `Source` (from Akka Reactive Streams) but you are building a Java 8 `Stream`.

The problem can be easily solved if you used `select` instead of `selectAll` when querying the database. Lagom's `CassandraSession` provides two families of meqthods to query the DB: (1) `select(...)` will immediately return a `Source<Row,NotUsed>` which is a reactive stream or (2) `selectAll(...)` which will gather all rows in memory and return a `List<Row>`. The latter could take your server down because will try to put all the info in memory. The former will use reactive streams to deliver items adapting the speed to your consuming end speed (backpressure) keeping a very low memory footprint.

Your code can be rewritten as:

```
 public ServiceCall<NotUsed, Source<GreetingMessage, ?>> getGreetings() {
    return request ->
         CompletableFuture.completedFuture(
              session.select("SELECT * FROM greetings")
                     .map(row -> new GreetingMessage(row.getString(0)))
          );
 }
```

Using `select` creates a `Source<>`. You can map items individually on that `Source<>` using the lambda you already developed.

Comment: Thanks! Now my code seems to compile, but now when I make the request, I get the HTTP response 426 Update Required with the message 'Upgrade to WebSocket required'. Any idea ?

Comment: Any time your `ServiceCall` uses a `Source` in one of it's parametrized types (like you are doing on the response type), Lagom will implement the call using websockets. You need a client that can upgrade the protocol to websockets (and that's what `426...` is saying ;-) )